# PubSubClient constructor parameter type mismatch

Tags: esp32

I am just learning an Arduino so this is totally educational purpose call.

I want to instantiate `PubSubClient` client with `WiFiClient` parameter.

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

WiFiClient *wifi = NULL;
PubSubClient client(wifi);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

compilation gives me back:

```
Compilation error: no matching function for call to /home/tepo/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:116:4: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/home/tepo/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:88:7: note: candidate: 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(const PubSubClient&)'
 class PubSubClient : public Print {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/tepo/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:88:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'WiFiClient*' to 'const PubSubClient&'

exit status 1

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(WiFiClient*&)'
```

and listing all the other constructors.

type chain seems to hold:
`class WiFiClient : public ESPLwIPClient` -> `class ESPLwIPClient : public Client` -> `class Client: public Stream`

`PubSubClient` ctor:

```
 PubSubClient(Client& client);
```

so why is it not accepting a WifiClient as a parameter?

Comment: `PubSubClient client(*wifi);`. it will compile, but it will just crash in runtime since there will be no WiFiClient object at address 0

Comment: look at the example code in the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering with the PubSubClient constructor in Arduino is related to how you're passing the WiFiClient object. You're currently using a pointer (WiFiClient *wifi), but the PubSubClient constructor expects a reference to a Client object, not a pointer.

The WiFiClient class inherits from the Client, so it can be used with PubSubClient. However, you need to pass an instance of WiFiClient, not a pointer to an instance.

Here's how you can correct your code:

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

WiFiClient wifi;
PubSubClient client(wifi);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

In this corrected version, wifi is an instance of WiFiClient, not a pointer. When you pass wifi to the PubSubClient constructor, it correctly matches the expected Client& client parameter type.

In C++ a pointer (WiFiClient *) is a variable that holds the memory address of an object.
A reference (WiFiClient &) is an alias for an object.
The PubSubClient constructor expects a reference because it needs to interact with the Client object throughout its lifecycle, and references are generally safer and more straightforward to use in this context than pointers.

Comment: yeah, that got it working; however I'm failing to understand where the actual instance of 'wifi' is comming from as I'm not constructing int, rather in the sketch I am using WifiManager that seems 'injecting' it to the declared variable. (I come from java-spring world) That's why I thought pointer will do in this case; it seems a bit weird to me it just "gets supplied" somehow..

Comment: What do you mean you're not constructing it? `WiFiClient wifi;` constructs it. Unlike Java you don't need to do a `new` procedurally to instantiate a class variable.